# is there a way to solve importing ternsorflow for keras problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\surik\anaconda3\envs\issa\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\surik\anaconda3\envs\issa\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

the tensorflow version i was using was 2.2.2 and keras version using was 2.4.3 and the python versionis 3.7.0

Comment: are you sure your tensorflow version is >2.2? you can cross check again print(tf.__version__)

Comment: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'" This points that the problem is that tensorflow is not installed

Comment: yes the version is 2.2.2

Comment: It looks like you're doing this in a virtual environment. If you are, did you remember to install in the same environment? (It's either an easy mistake to make, or I'm just terrible at remembering. Or possibly both.) What does `pip list` say?

Answer (score 0):

Try pip installing TensorFlow directly to your anaconda environment.

Comment: already installed to the environment but still get the same error